How can I bump a question with low rep?
I posted a question as a Guest, but then I signed up and wasn't the asker anymore. Unfortunately I didn't get the answer I wanted, so how do I get attention to it?
Where are these minifigures from?

In terms of raising awareness - once you have more reputation you can offer a bounty on the question to raise awareness of it, and before then you can share the question on social networks - if you use the "Share" link under the question you'll get a shorter link to it that includes your user id so that you are credited with the referrals.

With regards to your two accounts, you can ask the SO team to merge the accounts:

I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?
If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please sign into either account, visit the contact form and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.

I assume you're referring to the following accounts:

Guest - 6815 - Unregistered
Guest - 6822 - Registered

And we'd be merging 6815 into 6822?
